# Efficient caching solution for strings extracted from large number of text files

Tags: sqlite, perl, caching

For a bunch of text files (all very small with ~100 lines) in a directory, I need to build some string and then pipe everything into `fzf` so that the user can select one file. The string itself depends on the first few (~20) lines of the file and is built using a couple of very simple regex patterns. Between successive calls, it is expected that only a few files will have changed. I'm looking for some way to do this without noticeable delay (for the user) for about 50k files.

**Here is what I did so far:** My first solution for this was a naive shell script, namely:

`cat $dir/**/* | $process_script | fzf`

where $process_script is some Perl script which reads each text file line by line until it has built the required string and then prints it. Already with 1000 files to process, this script is no longer usable as it takes about two seconds and therefore incurs a noticeable delay for the user. So I implemented a poor man's cache by storing the strings in some text file and then only update those lines which have actually changed (based on the mtime of the files). The new script roughly does:

```sh
$find_files_with_mtime_newer_than_last_script_run | $process_script | fzf
```

where $find_files_with_mtime_newer_than_last_script_run runs `fd` (a fast find replacement) and $process_script is a Perl script of the form

```perl
my $cache = slurp($cachefile); #read lines of cachefile into multiline string
my ($string,$id);

while (<>) {

      ($string, $id) = build_string($_); #open file and build string

      $cache = s/^.*$id.*\n//; #delete old string from cache

      $cache = $cache . $string; #insert updated string into cache

}

print $cache;

spew($cache, $cachefile); #write cachefile

spew(printf('%s', time),$mtimefile); #store current mtime
```

Here, `slurp`, `spew` and `build_string` do what is written in the comments. Right now, this solution is fast enough for the user to not notice any delay, but I suspect that this will change again when the number of files grows.

**My question** As written above, I'm looking for some way to speed this task up. In particular, could you please comment if the following strategy should result in an acceptable (i.e. less than a second) runtime:

*Replace the plain text cache file with an SQLite file (or something similar), which stores the built string together with the corresponding filename and its last processing time, then pass the current time to the script, extract all files which need to be updated directly from SQLite without using find or `fd` and parallelize the processing for those files which need to be updated using gnu parallel.*

Of course, I'd also be very thankful for different solutions.

Comment: Does `@cache = s/\A.*$id.*\n//;` contain a typo or two?  It looks like it might not be doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @JimDavis Yes, there were some typos (which should no be fixed), thanks for pointing this out. Actually I'm reading the cache file into a string. Currently everything is working as it should with about 1500 files using the strategy explained above, I'm just afraid that performance will decrease once the number of files gets larger.

Comment: Since your current solution works without storing each file's _last processing time_ individually, why do you consider this for the other strategy?

Comment: @Armali I actually look up the mtime when creating the string, but you're right, there's technically no need to store it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**   *The first part has an approach using a cache file, the second one an approach with `sqlite`, and then there is a comparison between the two.*

---

Whether any one solution is going to be "fast enough" for the purpose depends entirely on all those numbers, of course. So does the best approach to take.

For what you show -- tiny files of which very few change -- basics should be good enough

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $fcache = 'cache.txt';  # format: filename,epoch,processed_string

open my $fh, '<', $fcache or die "Can't open $fcache: $!";
my %cache = map { chomp; my @f = split /,/, $_, 3;  shift @f => \@f } <$fh>; #/
close $fh;

for (@ARGV) {
    my $mtime = (stat)[9];

    # Have to process the file (and update its record)
    if ( $cache{$_}->[0] < $mtime ) { 
        @{$cache{$_}} = ($mtime, proc_file($_));
    }   

    say $cache{$_}->[1];
}

# Update the cache file
open my $fh_out, '>', $fcache or die "Can't open $fcache: $!";
say $fh_out join(',', $_, @{$cache{$_}}) for keys %cache;
    
sub proc_file {  # token processing: join words with _
    my $content = do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $_[0]; <> };
    return join '_', split ' ', $content;
}
```

Notes

- This will not preserve the order of records in the cache since a hash is used, what doesn't appear to matter. If it is needed then you'd need to know (record) the existing order of lines and then sort like that before writing
- Choices of the exact structure of the "cache" file and of the data structure used in the program for it are a little arbitrary, as samples. Improve that, by all means
- There must already exist a cache files for the above to work, in a format given in a comment: `filename,seconds-since-epoch,string`.  Add code to write it if it doesn't exist
- The biggest consumer here is the line populating a complex data structure from a 50k-line file. That should stay the most time consuming part as long as files are small and only a few need processing

I'd say that involving `sqlite` would mostly add overhead for such a small problem.

If the number of files to process each time grows beyond a handful then you may want to try it in parallel -- given how small they are the bulk of the time is spent on overhead in accessing files and perhaps there's enough "elbow room" there so to gain from parallel processing.  Also, in general I/O certainly can be sped up by running in parallel but that depends entirely on circumstances.

---

I thought that this was a perfect case to compare with `sqlite`, as I'm not certain what to expect.

First, I write 50,000 tiny files (`a N b`) into a separate directory (`dir`)

```
perl -wE'for (1..50_000) { open $fh, ">dir/f$_.txt"; say $fh "a $_ b" }'
```

(always use three-argument `open` normally!)   This took 3 seconds on my old laptop.

Now we need to build a cache file and a (`sqlite`) database with these files, then update a handful of them, and then compare processing using programs with `sqlite` and with a cache file.

Here is first the code for the approach using `sqlite`.

Make and populate the database, in a file `files.db`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
use DBI;

my ($dir, $db) = ('dir', 'files.db');
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:SQLite:dbname=$db", '', '', { RaiseError => 1 });

my $table = 'files';
my $qry = qq( create table $table (
    fname   text     not null unique,
    mtime   integer  not null,
    string  text
); );
my $rv = $dbh->do($qry);

chdir $dir or die "Can't chdir to $dir: $!";    
my @fnames = glob "*.txt";

# My sqlite doesn't accept much past 500 rows in single insert (?)
# The "string" that each file is digested into: join words with _
my $tot_inserted = 0;
while (my @part = splice @fnames, 0, 500) {
    my @vals;
    for my $fname ( @part ) { 
        my $str = join '_', 
            split ' ', do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $fname; <> };
        push @vals, "('$fname'," . (stat $fname)[9] . ",'$str')";
    }   
    my $qry = qq(insert into $table (fname,mtime,string) values ) 
            . join ',', @vals;

    $tot_inserted += $dbh->do($qry);
}
say "Inserted $tot_inserted rows";
```

This took around 13 seconds, a one-time expense.  I `insert` 500 rows at a time since my `sqlite` won't let me do much more; I don't know why that is so (I've pushed `PostgreSQL` to a few million rows in a single insert statement). Having the `unique` constraint on a column [gets it indexed](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).

Now we can change a few timestamps

```
touch dir/f[1-9]11.txt
```

and then run a program to update the `sqlite` database for these changes

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
use DBI;    
use Cwd qw();
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday tv_interval);

my $time_beg = [gettimeofday];

my ($dir, $db) = ('dir', 'files.db');
die "No database $db found\n" if not -f $db;    
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:SQLite:dbname=$db", '', '', { RaiseError => 1 });

# Get all filenames with their timestamps (seconds since epoch)
my $orig_dir = Cwd::cwd;
chdir $dir or die "Can't chdir to $dir: $!";
my %file_ts = map { $_ => (stat)[9] } glob "*.txt";

# Get all records from the database and extract those with old timestamps    
my $table = 'files';
my $qry = qq(select fname,mtime,string from $table);    
my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($qry);
my @new_rows = grep { $_->[1] < $file_ts{$_->[0]} } @$rows;
say "Got ", 0+@$rows, " records, ", 0+@new_rows, " with new timestamps";

# Reprocess the updated files and update the record
foreach my $row (@new_rows) { 
    @$row[1,2] = ( $file_ts{$row->[0]}, proc_file($row->[0]) );
}

printf "Runtime so far: %.2f seconds\n", tv_interval($time_beg);  #--> 0.34

my $tot_updated = 0;
$qry = qq(update $table set mtime=?,string=? where fname=?);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($qry);
foreach my $row (@new_rows) {
    $tot_updated += $sth->execute($sth);
}
say "Updated $tot_updated rows";

$dbh->disconnect;
printf "Runtime: %.2f seconds\n", tv_interval($time_beg);  #--> 1.54

sub proc_file {
    return join '_',
        split ' ', do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $_[0]; <> };
}
```

This expressly doesn't print. I left that out since there are a few ways to do it while I wasn't sure what exactly need be printed. I'd probably run another `select` for that, after it's all updated.

The program takes, remarkably consistently, around 1.35 seconds averaged over a few runs. But up to the part where it `update`-s the database for those (few!) changes it takes around 0.35 seconds, and I don't see why the `update` of a handful of records takes that long in comparison.

Next, in order to compare we need to complete the **approach using a cache file** from the first part of this post by writing that cache file (what was left out there). The complete program is very slightly different from the one from the beginning

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
use Cwd qw();

my ($dir, $cache) = ('dir', 'cache.txt');
if (not -f $cache) { 
    open my $fh, '>', $cache or die "Can't open $cache: $!";
    chdir $dir or die "Can't chdir to $dir: $!";
    my @fnames = glob "*.txt"; 
    for my $fname (@fnames) { 
        say $fh join ',', $fname, (stat $fname)[9],
            join '_', split ' ', do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $fname; <> };
    }
    say "Wrote cache file $cache, exiting.";
    exit;
}

open my $fh, '<', $cache or die "Can't open $cache $!";
my %fname = map { chomp; my @f = split /,/,$_,3; shift @f => \@f } <$fh>; #/

my $orig_dir = Cwd::cwd;
chdir $dir or die "Can't chdir to $dir: $!";
my @fnames = glob "*.txt";

for my $f (@fnames) {
    my $mtime = (stat $f)[9];

    # Have to process the file (and update its record)
    if ( $fname{$f}->[0] < $mtime ) { 
        @{$fname{$f}} = ($mtime, proc_file($f));
        say "Processed $f, updated with: @{$fname{$f}}";
    }   

    #say $fname{$_}->[1];  # 50k files! suppressed for feasible testing
}
   
# Update the cache
chdir $orig_dir  or die "Can't chdir to $orig_dir: $!";
open my $fh_out, '>', $cache or die "Can't open $cache: $!";
say $fh_out join(',', $_, @{$fname{$_}}) for keys %fname;


sub proc_file {
    return join '_', 
        split ' ', do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $_[0]; <> };
}
```

Writing the cache initially takes around 1 second.  After a few files are `touch`-ed like in the `sqlite` test the next run of this program takes, again rather consistently, around 0.45 seconds.

With these tests I have to conclude that the `sqlite` approach is a bit slower for these conditions.  But it is of course far more scalable, while projects only tend to grow in size.  Recall also that the `update` of the database takes quite a bit (relatively), what surprises me; there may be something off with my code and it may be possible to speed that up.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So basically the difference to my current implementation is that you're using a hash, circumventing the need for regular expressions (and hence going through the whole cache) when updating the cache. Simple and elegant! I'll try this out on the weekend and report here afterwards.

Comment: @F.Carbon I've added full code that uses `sqlite`, and compared with the cache-file based one.  Tested with 50k (teeny-tiny) files :).  I'll surely tweak things around (always do) but have a look

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions as I would expect this:

> Replace the plain text cache file with an sqlite file (or something similar), which stores the built string together with the corresponding filename, and its last processing time

Yes, this will speed up the process. The overhead of using DBI and DBD::SQLite (and OPENING the file) is less than 10 ms on my machine.

> , then pass the current time to the script, extract all files which need to be updated directly from sqlite without using find or fd

yes - that can be done by a single select on an indexed column.

> and parallelize the processing for those files which need to be updated using gnu parallel.

Here I would doubt that. I would guess the overall limiting factor to be IO. So parallelizing the process won't help.

The most interesting part here, is that use of the SQLite scales. It doesn't matter (for the processing part) if the cache contains 1000 or 100000 files, only whether 10 or 1000 files changed.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! Actually I made a mistake by saying that the current time is enough to find all files which need to be updated (this would result in all files being updated every time the script is called), it is actually necessary to look at the mtimes of every file individually. So in this case I don't think sqlite is a lot of help (unless lookups are significantly faster than querying a perl hash stored in memory, which I doubt). Still, it is very useful to know that the overhead of using it is negligible.

Comment: Using the sqlitedb also has the benefit of not reading in the cache. A select statement as almost as quick as a hash-lookup, but the "slurping, parsing and saving" of the cache-file are quasi immediate in the sqlite.

Comment: Parallelized I/O *can* be faster: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124527/speed-up-copying-1000000-small-files The only way to know for sure is to measure.

Comment: I've added full code for `sqlite`, see my update.  Curiously, the `update`-ing of the database to the (handful!) of changes in the end sets it back so that it is a little slower than the file-based code, otherwise it'd be a bit faster.  I'm not sure what to think of that... (Tested on 50k tiny files.)

Comment: Two issues: Reading the whole db to process the timestamps is a horrible idea (if the db is  big). You should consider some other mechanism to find out which files to be updated. (Set an arch attribute when processing them, so that only files without that attribute need to be processed? Rename them to .done, so all files without .dont need to be processed?)

Comment: second issue: Dont use `$dbh->do(..)`. Prepare the statement once and execute it for each record. `my $sth =  $dbh->prepare("update $table set mtime=? ,string=? where fname=?'')` and `$sth->execute($row->[1], $row->[2],$row->[0])` Preparing (Parsing/optimizing...) can take way longer than executing.

Comment: 1) "_should consider some other mechanism to find out which files to be update_"  --- well, like what? Using a db isn't a silver bullet.  Still need to find out which files changed and you have to, ahem, look at all files.  2)  Good call, thank you -- the stupid `do` remained from wanting a single statement, will update, thanks

Comment: Thank you for catching the `do`, updated.  Of course it makes _no difference at all_ on this handful of statements but it is how it should be done. (I never use `do`, just wanted to simplify here :(.

Comment: I also added the timing info -- the "_horrible_" idea results in 0.3 seconds flat, load and execution; can't go for nearly any less in a Perl program. (I've trimmed some to less than 0.2s load but that was with _no_ modules.) Besides, tell me how to check all timestamps without reading all timestamps :).   If you mean that I should have yet another, separate, db/records-file for stamps alone -- I'd still have to load the main one to make changes, even if for just one file.  And having a separate mechanism to check kinda defeats (some of the) benefits of using a db.

Comment: The whole thing reflects the fact, I think, that advantages of using a database don't quite come through in such a small problem. We're talking fractions of a second for the whole job.